# ¿tooltip-arrow parpadea cuando intento ingresar en el?

Tags: javascript, css

Css que se utiliza para el tooltip:

.

```
.popper,
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #009B67;
  color: white;
  width: 330px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tooltip-inner {
     overflow-x: auto;
}
 .tooltip-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
     margin: 5px; 
}

.tooltip-arrow {
    border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    color:#009B67;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas deberia decir que uso el tooltip.js de bootstrap, y lo que deseaba era interactuar entre el evento y el tooltip, pero nunca logro ingresar en el porque comienza a parpadear, realmente necesito ayuda Gracias

Comment: Tienes el valor en un label al momento de mostrar ?

Comment: Algo asi ? `<label tooltip="El total ingresos es el resultado de la suma de todos los ingresos." placement="top" show-delay="500">
                                                            <strong>Total ingresos y/o ventas brutas:
                                                                ${{acomuladorIngresos | currency:'':'' : '1.0'}}
                                                            </strong>
                                                        </label>`

Comment: Si los tengo dentro de una etiqueta con la clase tooltip,  el problema es cuando intento ingresar en el tooltip como que se desvanece o desaparece, lo que me gustaria es posible interactuar entre ellos ? La verdad es la primera vez que uso esta libreria y creo que no la estoy usando correctamente

Comment: Y si utilizas el ejemplo que te puse en el comentario? , puede que te sirva no es una clase es un atributo tooltip , yo lo he utilizado y no he tenido problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas el tooltip.js de boostrap entonces usas :

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {


                jQuery(element).tooltip(
                    {
                        title: event.title
                                ,html: true,placement:"top",trigger:"click"});


                    },
         }
```

- Si es asi aca veras las opciones por defectos con las que se origina:
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/
- Te daras cuenta que la propiedad por defecto es hover focus de alli, es donde al pasar el mouse y estar en foco es que aparece el tooltip, pero cuando intentas ingresar al tooltip perderas el foco, por lo tanto desaparecería, de ahí es el parpadeo. Coloca el trigger en click y asi podrias interactuar, el único inconveniente seria para que se vuelva ha cerrar  tendrías que volver hacer click.

Comment: Funciono ahora si puedo ingresar al tooltip, aunque me hubiera gustado conservar el efecto del hover y el focus y poder ingresar en el, gracias saludos